# Java Reactive hangs when calling repo operation inside map

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-webflux, reactive-mongo-java

I'm new to this reactive world and having an issue when I want to map my user to another user.

So the code is supposed to go to DB to find the user based on Username, then will need to create another user object and populate its Authority by calling another repository.

Then I need the value so I used **block**.

```
Mono<User> userMono = userService.findByUsername(regularUser.getUsername())
            .map(u -> {
                      User user = new User();
                      user.setUsername(u.getUsername());
                      user.setAuthority(userService.getAuthorities(u));
                      return user;
            });
User usr = userMono.block();
```

I found that every time the code executes the block, it will stop working. the request to DB is never completed. I debugged and found that in `Mono#block` - `BlockingSingleSubscriber#blockingGet` the `getCount()` is 1, which will go to `await()`. This takes forever. I waited but the `getCount()` didn't reach 0 and there was no `InterruptedException` thrown.
[blockingGet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIlmK.png)

```
UserService.java

@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
AuthorityRepository authorityRepository;

public Mono<User> findByUsername(String username) {
  return userRepository.findByUsername(username);
}
public Flux<Authority> getAuthorities(User user) {
  return authorityRepository.findAllByUserId(user.getId());
}
```

I'm using Spring Boot 2.7.0
io.spring.dependency-management 1.0.11.RELEASE
spring-boot-starter-webflux
spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive

Reactive UserDetailService bean that has the problem with calling repository inside a map

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public ReactiveAuthenticationManager reactiveAuthenticationManager(ReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsService,
                                                                   PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
    var authenticationManager = new UserDetailsRepositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager(userDetailsService);
    authenticationManager.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    return authenticationManager;
}

@Bean
public ReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsService(UserService userService) {

    return username -> userService.findByUsername(username)
            .log()
            .map(u -> org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
                    .withUsername(u.getUsername()).password(u.getPassword())                                .roles(userService.getRoles(u).toArray(String[]::new))
                    .accountExpired(!u.isActive())
                    .credentialsExpired(!u.isActive())
                    .disabled(!u.isActive())
                    .accountLocked(!u.isActive())
                    .build()
            );
}
```

If I hardcoded the roles (without going to the database) it works well.

I created a simple project that replicate the issue:
https://github.com/skyglassio/repository-await/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/demo/DevInitializer.java line 57. After `userMono.block();` is called it goes into a forever wait.

Comment: The second one you are missing a return.

Comment: Also you should avoid `.block()` unless there's a real reason to I learned that the hard way.  What you need to do is try to get it to be a Flux/Mono all the way through.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. The service is a snippet of what I wrote to show what the service does. I wanted to use the returned value to create a security bean. That's the only way I know for now. Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you show how you are creating security Bean?

Comment: @nicholasnet I updated the post with the security bean, please take a look at ReactiveUserDetailsService

Comment: I've got very similar issue. However if I replace .block() with .subscribe() it doesn't stuck anymore. Suspecting a dependency stuff. Will keep you posted if a reason is found.